# Unable to ssh with authorized keys, password always prompted

Tags: centos7, ssh-keys

I've been through several posts here to try to correct this issue but I am being unable to do so.

A few days ago the login to the server with the **authorized_keys** mapped stopped working, there was no one changing the file or the folder itself, I am the only one that manipulates the server.

Following some posts in here, I tried re-creating the ssh key set and rename the old .ssh folder but it didn't work.

Another post mentioned that I had to change the permissions on .ssh to 750 and re-create the authorized_keys file again after a brand new .ssh was generated, and did not worked as well.

[Linux ssh folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KORXl.jpg)

Can someone assist me with this issue? I am not an advanced user.

The linux server is CentOS 7

### Edit

The output of ssh -vvv in the server as requested:

```
$ ssh -vvv root@131.72.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_8.2p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1e  17 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 131.72.xxx.xxx is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 131.72.222.241 [131.72.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 131.72.xxx.xxx:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 131.72.xxx.xxx
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:oDemkeTUNqSXDkAz6sx/w/978fNZR4QQsIYFfdb0BiA
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 131.72.xxx.xxx
debug1: Host '131.72.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:MgYlmw9i3/fmZCu8+0uIjZZu4qer+zJnKBh7epHx26w
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:MgYlmw9i3/fmZCu8+0uIjZZu4qer+zJnKBh7epHx26w
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/Andre Fr\303\263es/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
root@131.72.xxx.xxx's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 131.72.xxx.xxx ([131.72.xxx.xxx]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 4
debug1: Remote: Ignored authorized keys: bad ownership or modes for directory /root
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x48
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
```

Comment: That is the log from the client. You need to check the log from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong ownership on /root, in your first image (Linux ssh folder) when you show ls -lah ./ssh it is seen that ../ has ownership suporte.sutic.

```
chown -R root.root /root

chmod 0550 /root

chmod 0700 /root/.ssh

chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: This was it in the end, thank you all for your support! I was really lost here

Answer (score 1):

Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` it has a `Authentication` section. Check that `PubkeyAuthentication` isn't set to `no`. The configuration to the path to the `AuthorizedKeysFile` is also set there. Check those settings, adjust them if necessary and restart the sshd service using `systemctl restart sshd`. In case the `sshd_config` file looks fine investigate the problem using `journalctl -u sshd` it will display all the messages and errors related to sshd. If there is a permission problem with the AuthorizedKeysFile it should be in there.

Edit: Check journalctl before restarting sshd to reduce the risk of completely locking yourself out of the server.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! The config file seems ok, https://i.ibb.co/b1fKzTK/ssh-file-1.jpg, as per the logs, there are a lot of thing there, but I don't understand what that means, most of it is "pam_succeed_if(sshd:auth): requirement "uid >= 1000" not met by user "root""

Comment: Have you tried to connect with a non root user. Looks like that pam forbids that. You could check if PermitRootLogin is set to yes in the sshd_config. But I would recommend not to use root user to ssh on a server. Use an unprivileged user to ssh on the server and sudo to gain root privileges.

Comment: I just did, worked normally with the non root user as well

Comment: The PermitRootLogin is commented in the file, but in the comments, it is set to yes

Comment: If it is commented out it means that it defaults to prohibit-password. Which means that something with your /root/.ssh/authorized_keys could be wrong.

Comment: How can I verify if there is something wrong? I've done this same procedure with the other 2 machines, which was basically **vi authorized_keys** in the **.ssh** folder and paste the **id_rsa.pub** from the machine that I want to have direct access

Comment: double check that file. Happened to me more than once that I accidentally missed a part of the pub key.

Comment: Please add the output of `ssh -vvv` to the question.

Comment: I triple checked the id_rsa.pub and it was correct. Since I generated the id again, I had to replace it in  the other servers and it was ok, worked normally. Still no clue why only in this server the issue is happening.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, I've just added the output to the question as requested

Comment: Sorry, I meant `ssh -vvv user@hostname`, where user is the other system username and hostname is the server address. This will show detailed information about the connection process.

Comment: Done, the output is in the question

Comment: `Ignored authorized keys: bad ownership or modes for directory /root` check the permissions for `/root/.ssh`. It should be 600 (u=rw).

Comment: I done a "chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh/" but I am still unable to access straight to the server. Should I change it to  the entire /root folder?